# HashMap - correct usage?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i am trying to process an MMS message with multiple attachments. For that I'm creating a HashMap as following (this is not the complete implementation but only the relevant part):

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashAttachments = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int c = 0;
    if(atts != null) {
        for(Attachment a : atts){
            if(a.mimeType.startsWith("image/")){
                            <some code here>
                hashAttachments.put(a.fileName, indx);
            }else if(a.mimeType.startsWith("text/")){
                <some code here>
                hashAttachments.put("text_"+String.valueOf(c++)+".txt",indx);
            }
                    <some more mime types>
        } /* for */
```

the message I am trying to process has 4 attachments - two images and two texts, so I expect the hash map to contain 4 entries when the for loop is over.

What I actually see is that at some point one of the entries of the map is overwritten and I end up with 3 entries instead of 4. What could be a reason? (keys are unique, not null and not empty in all cases)

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: key set after each iteration (looks perfect, not what I saw inspecting keys in debugger):

```
10-16 21:50:01.207: INFO/System.out(27593): ~~~~~~~
10-16 21:50:01.207: INFO/System.out(27593): abc.jpg
10-16 21:50:01.207: INFO/System.out(27593): ~~~~~~~
10-16 21:50:01.217: INFO/System.out(27593): abc.jpg
10-16 21:50:01.217: INFO/System.out(27593): 2010-06-18_12.47.50.jpg
10-16 21:50:01.227: INFO/System.out(27593): ~~~~~~~
10-16 21:50:01.227: INFO/System.out(27593): abc.jpg
10-16 21:50:01.227: INFO/System.out(27593): 2010-06-18_12.47.50.jpg
10-16 21:50:01.227: INFO/System.out(27593): text_0.txt
10-16 21:50:01.237: INFO/System.out(27593): ~~~~~~~
10-16 21:50:01.237: INFO/System.out(27593): abc.jpg
10-16 21:50:01.237: INFO/System.out(27593): text_1.txt
10-16 21:50:01.237: INFO/System.out(27593): 2010-06-18_12.47.50.jpg
10-16 21:50:01.237: INFO/System.out(27593): text_0.txt
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you've shown, what's in the `<some code here>` blocks?

Comment: Which attachment entry is being overwritten in the HashMap?  Just to narrow it down.

Comment: @Mark: some code is some code that is not relevant to HashMap issue - I can comment it out and the problem will still be there

Comment: try `System.out.println()` ing the keys that you are putting in.  That should make it obvious which one is being overwritten, and therefore what your problem is.

Comment: @RD: the order is 2 images and then 2 texts. Images are added at 0 and 3 locations, then text is added at 4 and then the last text overwrites 3.

Comment: Can you print the `Map` after each iteration? That'd help us from a debug standpoint.

Comment: Or at least look at the return value from put when you are stepping through in the debugger.  The return value from put should be null if you are adding a new key, but it will equal the old value if you are overwriting a key's value.

Comment: So it doesn't look like you actually have an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you timestamped debug output being correct, please remember the following, regarding the HashMap class:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

from the javadoc:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

In the debugger, it may have looked like a key/value pair was being overwritten, but in reality, the insertion probably changed the order of the HashMap.  Testing the return value of put(...) is the best way to test if a new key/value is colliding with an existing key.